# Анимационный выезжающий блок на весь экран с кнопкой закрыть

Tags: javascript, css3

Подскажите, какие методы использовать чтобы доделать до логического завершения? Необходимо при клике на `#toggle` разворачивать `#collaps`. Также при клике должен удаляться `#toggle` с родителем, *а при закрытии `#collaps`, должен снова появиться `#toggle`.* *Собственно к последней части не знаю с какого бока подступиться.*

Название `id="collaps"` не самое лучшее, ведь по сути происходит и сворачивание и разворачивание. Какое лучше придумать?

```js
var elToggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
elToggle.addEventListener('click', drop);

function drop() {
  var collaps = document.getElementById('collaps');
  collaps.style.left = '0';
  collaps.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<button type="button" id="close" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeCollaps(this);">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>`);


  var parentEl = elToggle.parentNode;
  parentEl.remove(parentEl);
}
var removeCollaps = function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('close');
  var parentEl = button.parentNode;
  parentEl.remove(parentEl);
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

#collaps {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  transition-property: left;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#collaps>.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

.wrap-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF8DC;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFE4E1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

#toggle {
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #138ab2;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0);
  width: 34px;
  line-height: 0px;
  height: 34px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#toggle:hover {
  color: #B22222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">Основное содержимое страницы....</div>
</div>

<div id="collaps">
  <h1>Как пользоваться</h1>
  <p>Какой-то текст</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Жёлтый</li>
    <li>Красный</li>
    <li>Фиолетовый</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="wrap-toggle"><span id="toggle">Справка</span>
</div>
```

Почему этот же пример не сработывает в https://jsfiddle.net/a4Lndqkb/23/
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного упростил и подправил ваш код. Теперь всё работает:

```html
<!doctype html><html><head>
<style type="text/css">
*,
*::after,
*::before{box-sizing: border-box}

.container
{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.main{text-align: center}

#collaps
{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: -100%;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #FFF8DC;
 transition-property: left;
 transition-duration: 1s;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}

#collaps>.close
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 right: 20px;
}

.wrap-toggle
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0px;
 width: 34px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #FFF8DC;
 border-right: 1px solid #FFE4E1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
}

#toggle
{
 display: flex;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-family: Verdana, Arial;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #138ab2;
 -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(0);
 width: 34px;
 line-height: 0px;
 height: 34px;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

#toggle:hover{color: #B22222}
</style>
</head><body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="main">Основное содержимое страницы....</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap-toggle">
 <span id="toggle">Справка</span>
</div>

<div id="collaps">
 <h1>Как пользоваться</h1>
 <p>Какой-то текст</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Жёлтый</li>
  <li>Красный</li>
  <li>Фиолетовый</li>
 </ul>
 <button type="button" id="close" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="removeCollaps(this);"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', drop);

function drop()
{
 document.getElementById('collaps').style.left = '0';
}

function removeCollaps(obj)
{
 obj.parentNode.style.left = '-100%';
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Название `#collaps` лучше переименовать в `#switch`.

Comment: Хороший пример, многое подчерпнул. А не проясните как работает (obj)? Также что-то не вижу как удаляется блок .wrap-toggle с потомком.

Comment: @ikar, вы передаёте объект *obj* через onclick="removeCollaps(this), когда нажимаете на кнопку. Блок .wrap-toggle с потомком никуда удалять не нужно - он остаётся лежать внизу. HTML отображается слоями - что добавлено первым - лежит снизу. В данном случае div collaps просто лежит сверху, т.к. добавлен последним в контейнер body.